# how to return the number of occurrences of a pattern in a file, when i grep from another file?

Tags: awk, sed

I have two files. File 1 and file 2
Now i need to grep all the patterns that match file 1 in file two which can be done by grep -f.

But I need to know how many times each pattern from file 1 is occurring in file2 using awk or sed

for Example;

flie 1

abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
wxy

file 2;

Thanks for your interest in **abc**our search and

advertising services (the “Services**def**")!

By using our Services, you agree to these**abc**

terms (the “AdSense Terms”), the AdSense Program Policies and**stu** the Google

Branding Guidelines  (collectively, the “Agreement”)**abc**

If ever in conflict, to the extent of such conflict, **def** the AdSense Terms

will take precedence over any other terms of the Agreement.
Please read the Agreement carefully.
As used in the Agreement, “you” or “publisher” means 
the individual or entity using the Services (and/or any 
individual, entity or successor entity, agency or 
network acting on your behalf), “we,” “us” or “Google” 
means Google Inc., and the “parties” means you and Google.

now the code should return

abc found 3 times
def found 2 times
stu found 1 time

grep -f file1 file2 gives us the total patterns that match
grep -f file1 file2 | wc -l gives us the total number of matches..

Comment: post some examples on input and the output

Comment: "greping"? seriously?? Please post some examples of what you have tried so far.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Using the unix utilites: `tr ' ' '\n' <file1 | grep -f - -o file2 | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: didn't `grep -c -f file1 file2` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{pattern[ $0]=0};FNR!=NR && ($0 in pattern) {pattern[ $0]++};END{for( pat in pattern) if(pattern[pat]>0) print pattern[pat] ":" pat }' file1 file2
```

Assuming pattern are the whole string in both file.